# Jetpack not showing Approved comment

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, jetpack

Jetpack don't work on My Blog. visitor can comment i already get notification from admin menu that comment is placed i approved it but still i does not show.
frontpage show always no comment admin panel show 5 comment 1 approved.

My blog on wordpress url : [Design Spicy](http://designspicy.com/)
My jetpack code

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some themes hard code a comment form in place. WordPress has a function (comment_form()) that instead builds the comment form dynamically.

If your theme hard codes the comment form, you or the theme author will need to replace it with comment_form() in order for Jetpack Comments to work correctly.

If your theme already uses comment_form(), you should be all set.

If you continue to experience issues, I'd recommend deactivating all plugins other than Jetpack and see if the comment form works. If it does, start activating plugins one by one until the form breaks. At that point, you will have found a plugin conflict that you can report to us for investigation.

If none of this works, please get in touch with us at our support link. Include your site URL, theme name, active plugins, and a screenshot of your comment area.

Comment: i uses only jetpack 
suggest me some code for my comment.php

Comment: Is that worked? If yes... You can share here for other users too.. Who are struggling with same issues. We will appreciate your initiative

Answer (score 0):

For my case , i replace the form action code
by

> comment_form() code

The second problem : The existing comment appear below the jetpack form . 
So it remove all the code after comment_form()
and also remove the close loop of form action  /form

Example can be referred to http://www.webhostingreviewsolution.com/webhostingguide/